# GitLab 8.10 CE - Why is there no issue board in my project interface?

Tags: gitlab, issue-tracking, gitlab-ce

I've read about GitLab's issue board feature (see links below), but it's not there on my instance. Under the 'Issues' page of a project, all I see are 'Issues,' 'Labels' and 'Milestones' -- nothing about Issue Boards. Why is this? Do source installations not have this feature?

My GitLab setup:
Community Edition
Created from source
Version 8.10

https://about.gitlab.com/solutions/issueboard/
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UWsJ8tkHAa8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Issue boards](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/issue_board.html#issue-board) were introduced in Gitlab 8.11. Time to upgrade!

> Notes:
>
> Introduced in GitLab 8.11.
>
> The Backlog column was replaced by the Add issues button in GitLab 8.17.

Answer (score 1):

Note: with [GitLab 13.5](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2020/10/22/gitlab-13-5-released/#automatically-add-to-do-and-doing-lists-on-new-boards) (October 2020), you have pre-populated issue boards:

> ### Automatically add To Do and Doing lists on new boards
>
> In most cases, teams will be best served by keeping their workflows as simple as possible.
> To encourage this and make the first experience with a board more efficient and approachable, creating a new board will now automatically pre-populate **To Do** and **Doing** lists so you can get straight to managing issues.
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/issue_board.html#first-time-using-an-issue-board) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/202144).